# sample ant scripts to commit and retrieve from git hub using bit bucket

Tags: ant, github

We have a need to retrieve all metadata and apex classes from a salesforce org and push to a git hub repository hosted on bitbucket using ant.  I have used the ant migration tool which helps to retrieve all metadata and apex from the sandbox. I am struggling to create an ant task which would retrieve files from a github repository and commit to it. Do you guys have sample ant build files which can retrieve from github, push, commit and where do we store the login information for github?
Thanks
Buyan

Comment: Is there any specific reason you aren't doing this using a GUI like SourceTree? Just curious.

Comment: I need an automated way to create ant script so that i can build continous integration in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an SSH key to avoid storing the password, then use the sshexec task:

```
<target name="pull" description="Git pull">
  <sshexec host="${host}"
         username="${user}"
         keyfile="c:\paul\testkey"
         trust="true"
         command="git pull"/>
</target>
```

**References**

- [Ant Tasks for Git](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2008/11/ant-tasks-for-git/)
- [Creating SSH keys - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html)
- [Set up an SSH key - Atlassian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html)
- [linux - Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-asking-me-for-my-ssh-key-passphrase)
- [ssh - ANT SSHEXEC task Issues using keyfile - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781124/ant-sshexec-task-issues-using-keyfile)
- [Solved: git with ssh authentication prompts for password](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-with-ssh-authentication-prompts-for-password/qaq-p/88415)